# How do I format chat app to show ellipses for the side bar, and keep each div highlighted after being clicked?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm building an HTML chat app template, and I ran into two major issues when trying to complete it.

1. The chat names on the side are not showing ellipses despite me using `text-overflow: ellipse;`
2. When anyone of the chats are clicked, I would like them to stay on an active color until I click on another one, but I'm not sure how to go about it.

Here's my HTML and CSS:

```css
body{
    background-image: url("../img/gradientBackgroundOne.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
}

.wrapper{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 2fr;
    width:  85vw;
    height: 80vh;
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 2%;
}

/* 
* This section will style the sidebar, which will contain all of the users chats that they're in
*
*/
.sidebar{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: 80px 60vh auto;
    background-color: purple;
}

.sidebar > .chats-title{
    background-color: violet;
}

.sidebar > .group-chats{
    overflow-y: auto;
    background-color: white;
}


.sidebar > .group-chats > .group-chat-name{
    padding: 15px;
    background-color: chocolate;
    border: 1px solid black;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

.sidebar > .group-chats > div:hover{
    background-color:burlywood;
}

.sidebar > .group-chats > div:active{
    background-color:rgb(122, 184, 235);
}

.sidebar > .add-new-chat{
    background-color: turquoise;
}

/**************************************/
/*       END OF SIDE BAR STYLING!     */
/**************************************/


/* 
* This section will style the chat, which will contain all of the users messages that they're in
*
*/
.chat-container{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr 8fr auto;
}

.chat-container > .chat{
    background-color: red;
}

.chat-container > .message-container{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 5% auto;
}

.chat-container > .chat-title{
    display: grid;
    background-color: chartreuse;
    border: 2px solid black;
}  

.chat-container > .message-container > .image-bk{
    display: grid;
    background-color: blue;
}

.chat-container > .chat-title > .title-text{
    color: white;
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin: auto;
}

/**************************************/
/*       END OF CHAT STYLING!     */
/**************************************/

/* Icon styling */
i{
    margin: auto;
    /* font-size: 1.6rem;  */
    color: rgb(240, 240, 240);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="../static/img/fav.png" type="image/x-icon">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../static/css/example.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.3.0/font/bootstrap-icons.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <title>Document</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Mini-Messenger</a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
              <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
              <ul class="navbar-nav">
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="#">DM</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="#">Message History</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="#">Log Out</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>

        <div class="wrapper">
            <div class="sidebar">
                <div class="chats-title">
                    <h1>Chats</h1>
                </div>

                <div class="group-chats">
                    <div class="group-chat-name">
                        <div> <b>L.R.D.D </b>  </div> 
                        <div>Luis: They weren't fresh, but boy they were high quality</div> 
                    </div>
                    <div class="group-chat-name">
                        <div> <b>Munckin and Me!</b> </div>
                        <div>Denise: Hey DD</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="group-chat-name"> 
                        <div> <b>The boiz</b></div>
                        <div>Vincent: Hehehe Steve dumb hehehe</div>
                    </div class="group-chat-name">
                    <div class="group-chat-name">
                        <div> <b>Example2</b> </div>
                        <div> Fred: I am fred, look at me! </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="group-chat-name">
                        <div> <b>Example3</b>  </div>
                        <div>Mark: Woah dude, farizzle! </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="group-chat-name">
                        <div> <b>Magical School Bus </b> </div>
                        <div>Arthur: Oh dear god, Please let this be a normal field trip! :( </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="add-new-chat">
                    <h3>Add new chat!</h3>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="chat-container">
                <div class="chat-title">
                    <div class="title-text">
                        <b>L.R.D.D </b> 
                    </div> 
                </div>

                <div class="chat">

                </div>

                <div class="message-container">
                     <div class="image-bk">
                        <i class="bi bi-image"></i>
                    </div>  
                    <form>
                        <input type="text" class="form-rounded form-control form-control-md" required name="send-message" placeholder="Send message" aria-label="Recipient's username" aria-describedby="basic-addon2">
                    </form> 
                </div>                 
            </div>

        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

What should I do? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You probably have to use javascript to achieve this. The default functioning for the :active state is to snap back to the :hover state as soon as you click and release the mouse button.

```
.sidebar > .group-chats > div:active {
    background-color: red;
}
```

If you remove the :hover state you'll make it stay red, but it's as far as I am concerned impossible to keep :active as long as :hover immediately takes over once the click is finished.

```css
body{
    background-image: url("../img/gradientBackgroundOne.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
}

.wrapper{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 2fr;
    width:  85vw;
    height: 80vh;
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 2%;
}

/* 
* This section will style the sidebar, which will contain all of the users chats that they're in
*
*/
.sidebar{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: 80px 60vh auto;
    background-color: purple;
}

.sidebar > .chats-title{
    background-color: violet;
}

.sidebar > .group-chats{
    overflow-y: auto;
    background-color: white;
}


.sidebar > .group-chats > .group-chat-name{
    padding: 15px;
    background-color: chocolate;
    border: 1px solid black;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

.sidebar > .group-chats > div:hover{
    background-color:burlywood;
}

.sidebar > .group-chats > div:active,
.sidebar > .group-chats > div:focus {
    background-color: red;
}

.sidebar > .add-new-chat{
    background-color: turquoise;
}

/**************************************/
/*       END OF SIDE BAR STYLING!     */
/**************************************/


/* 
* This section will style the chat, which will contain all of the users messages that they're in
*
*/
.chat-container{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr 8fr auto;
}

.chat-container > .chat{
    background-color: red;
}

.chat-container > .message-container{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 5% auto;
}

.chat-container > .chat-title{
    display: grid;
    background-color: chartreuse;
    border: 2px solid black;
}  

.chat-container > .message-container > .image-bk{
    display: grid;
    background-color: blue;
}

.chat-container > .chat-title > .title-text{
    color: white;
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin: auto;
}

/**************************************/
/*       END OF CHAT STYLING!     */
/**************************************/

/* Icon styling */
i{
    margin: auto;
    /* font-size: 1.6rem;  */
    color: rgb(240, 240, 240);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="../static/img/fav.png" type="image/x-icon">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../static/css/example.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.3.0/font/bootstrap-icons.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <title>Document</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Mini-Messenger</a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
              <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
              <ul class="navbar-nav">
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="#">DM</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="#">Message History</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="#">Log Out</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>

        <div class="wrapper">
            <div class="sidebar">
                <div class="chats-title">
                    <h1>Chats</h1>
                </div>

                <div class="group-chats">
                    <div class="group-chat-name">
                        <div> <b>L.R.D.D </b>  </div> 
                        <div>Luis: They weren't fresh, but boy they were high quality</div> 
                    </div>
                    <div class="group-chat-name">
                        <div> <b>Munckin and Me!</b> </div>
                        <div>Denise: Hey DD</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="group-chat-name"> 
                        <div> <b>The boiz</b></div>
                        <div>Vincent: Hehehe Steve dumb hehehe</div>
                    </div class="group-chat-name">
                    <div class="group-chat-name">
                        <div> <b>Example2</b> </div>
                        <div> Fred: I am fred, look at me! </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="group-chat-name">
                        <div> <b>Example3</b>  </div>
                        <div>Mark: Woah dude, farizzle! </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="group-chat-name">
                        <div> <b>Magical School Bus </b> </div>
                        <div>Arthur: Oh dear god, Please let this be a normal field trip! :( </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="add-new-chat">
                    <h3>Add new chat!</h3>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="chat-container">
                <div class="chat-title">
                    <div class="title-text">
                        <b>L.R.D.D </b> 
                    </div> 
                </div>

                <div class="chat">

                </div>

                <div class="message-container">
                     <div class="image-bk">
                        <i class="bi bi-image"></i>
                    </div>  
                    <form>
                        <input type="text" class="form-rounded form-control form-control-md" required name="send-message" placeholder="Send message" aria-label="Recipient's username" aria-describedby="basic-addon2">
                    </form> 
                </div>                 
            </div>

        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Edit: Forgot your ellipsis question. For this to work your element has to have a width. However, I am not able to solve it, your markup and css are confusing and adding width to what I think is the correct element doesn't work.

Edit 2: You could try a JS solution like this to make the active background color stick when you click the chat room divs. I have simplified. You can change this to use the container class that you already have and just add a unique class to all the divs inside of it that you want to make work with this JS:

```js
const container = document.querySelector('.container')

const activeState = (e) => {
    document.querySelectorAll('.active-color').forEach(link => link.classList.remove('clicked-color'))
  if (e.target.className.toLowerCase() === 'active-color' )
    e.target.classList.add('clicked-color')
  }

  container.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    activeState(e)
  })
```

```css
div.active-color {
  padding: 2rem;
  width: 300px;
  background: #ddd;
  margin: 1rem 0;
  border-radius: 6px;
}

div.active-color:hover,
div.active-color:focus {
  background: purple;
  cursor: pointer;
}

div.active-color:active {
  background: red;
}

div.active-color.clicked-color {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="active-color">DIV 1</div>
  <div class="active-color">DIV 2</div>
  <div class="active-color">DIV 3</div>
  <div class="active-color">DIV 4</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Okay, so I actually was able to figure out why the ellipsis was not showing, and it was that I had to either remove the divs around the text in the `<div class="group-chat-name> </div>` or apply the ellipsis styling to the inner div of the `<div class="group-chat-name> </div>`. The javascript part is tricky though because I can't just reference any particular div like I can a button, it has to be any div in the class `<div class="group-chats">`. Also, sorry for the lack of organization, CSS is not my specialty.

Comment: I have edited my answer and suggested a vanilla javascript solution that would help you make the div color stick on clicks. Let me know if you can make this work.